# How to stop word wrapping in emacs

Tags: emacs

I was playing around with word wrapping yesterday and now I am getting an annoying behavior in my emacs (23.1).  When typing in my latex documents the paragraphs are automatically wrapping.  As an example, if I open a finished tex document and want to add a space in the middle of a paragraph the entire paragraph gets resized from covering the entire width of the screen to only covering approximately 1/4 of the screen (lines are wrapping around 68-72 columns wide).

Prior to changing anything I saved my original .emacs file, and I have restored the original .emacs to no benefit.  I suspect I may have screwed something up in my AucTex configuration, but I cannot find anything to fix this.  Any pointers on places to check will be appreciated.

Comment: `M-x auto-fill-mode` to toggle the wrapping, `ESC-120 C-x f` to change the justification width.

Comment: And you can put `(auto-fill-mode -1)` in your init file to disable it by default, if something you load has enabled it. Put that sexp after whatever is turning it on.

Comment: Changing the justification width seems to have fixed the problem.  Can I set this in my .emacs file somehow?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can fix this problem with `(remove-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode)`. If that doesn't work, try `LaTeX-mode-hook` or `latex-mode-hook` or maybe even `auctex-mode-hook`. If none of those work, try running `C-h v tex-mode-hook` (on all the hooks) and posting the answer you get.

Comment: That did it.  I had (add-hook 'tex-mode-hook 'auto-fill-mode) hidden away within my .emacs file.  I commented that out and all seems to be well now.  Thanks again, very helpful.